# InitialAdminPassword file not present inside var/jenkins_home/secret folder

Tags: docker, jenkins

Hi All I am trying to run a Jenkins on my machine(linux) using docker container.
When I'm running a  Jenkins docker container it's  running successfully,

But It's not showing the initialAdminPassword in the console.
[image]

So I tried checking the password in the initialAdminPassword file inside
Jenkins container using docker exec command but couldn't found the file.

[image]

I even tried with super user but the result was same.

[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  This "how do I deploy Jenkins" question doesn't seem like a programming-related question, but if you think it is on-topic for Stack Overflow, please [edit] the question to replace the image attachments with the actual commands you're running and their plain-text output.

Comment: Long as the initialAdminPassword file is not present. try deleting the Jenkins container and starting a new one. This will ensure that you are starting with a fresh Jenkins installation.

Comment: I tried deleting the container multiple times but the result was same .